# Explicit estimates on summability kernels

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

A "[summability kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summability_kernel)" is a sequence of functions $k_n:[0,1)\to \mathbb C$ such that
$$ \int_0^1 k_n(t) \mathrm d t =1,$$
$$ \int_0^1 |k_n(t)| \mathrm d t =O(1),$$ with an implied constant independent of $n$
and, lastly, $k_n$ must satisfy that for every $\delta \in (0,1/2]$,
$$ \lim_{n\to+\infty}\int_{\delta<|t|<1/2} |k_n(t)| \mathrm d t =0.$$

My question is whether we can choose a summability kernel such that the limit in the third property converges faster than the [Fejér kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r_kernel). Specifically, the Fejér kernel is defined as $$F_n(t) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{|k|\leq n-1} \left(1-\frac{|k|}{n}\right)\mathrm e^{2\pi i k t}$$ and one can show that it is given in closed form as $$F_n(t)=\frac{1}{n}\frac{1-\cos(n t) }{1-\cos t}.$$ This is $\ll     \frac{1}{n|1-\cos t|}$, which is $\ll 1/(n t^2)$ from the Taylor expansion of $\cos$ around $t=0$.
Hence
$$\int_{\delta<|t|<1/2} |k_n(t)| \mathrm d t \asymp \frac{1}{n \delta}.$$
This goes to zero as long as $$\delta>\frac{1}{n^{1.0001}},$$ say.

QUESTION: is there any other kernel such that the limit goes to zero even when $\delta $ is not so large compared to $n$? For example, when $$\delta>\frac{1}{n^c}$$ for some constant $0<c<1$ ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to improve the degree of approximation of Fejer kernel with trigonometric polynomials of degree n (which is of order $L (\log n)/n$ for Lipchitz functions) to the optimal one which is $L/n$ , again for Lipschitz function. This is done by the Jackson kernel. I do not know the answer for your $n, \delta$ question, since usually these improved estimates are proved by integrating $tk_n(t)$, rather then splitting.

Comment: This is excellent! May I please ask how is the degree of approximation defined? I do not work in this area at all...

Comment: For $f$ continuous and periodic $e_n(f)=\inf\{\|f-P\|_\infty \}$ where $P$ ranges over all trigonometric polynomials of degree $\leq n$. You can find all this, for example, in the book by Natanson, Constructive Approximation (and in many others).